# Calculate Cumulative sum for previous 6 months

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

| RECORD | ATTRIBUTE | DATE | MONTH | AMT | CML AMT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1/1/2021 | 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | A | 2/1/2021 | 2 | 10 | 20 |
| 3 | A | 3/1/2021 | 3 | 10 | 30 |
| 4 | A | 4/1/2021 | 4 | 10 | 40 |
| 5 | A | 5/1/2021 | 5 | 10 | 50 |
| 6 | A | 6/1/2021 | 6 | 10 | 60 |
| 7 | B | 1/1/2021 | 1 | 20 | 20 |
| 8 | B | 3/1/2021 | 3 | 20 | 40 |
| 9 | B | 5/1/2021 | 5 | 20 | 60 |
| 10 | B | 7/1/2021 | 7 | 20 | 80 |
| 11 | B | 9/1/2021 | 9 | 20 | 80 |
| 12 | B | 11/1/2021 | 11 | 20 | 80 |
| 13 | C | 1/1/2021 | 1 | 30 | 30 |
| 14 | C | 8/1/2021 | 8 | 30 | 30 |
| 15 | C | 9/1/2021 | 9 | 30 | 60 |

I am looking to calculate the cumulative sum (CML AMT column) using the AMT column for the past 6 months.
The CML AMT column should only look at window of 6 Months.
If there is no other record for the same attribute within a 6 month time frame, then it should simply return the AMT column.

I tried the below which clearly wont work as the dates/months are not consistent.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
SUM(AMT)
OVER (PARTITION BY ATTRIBUTE
      ORDER BY DATE
      ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Teradata doesn't support `RANGE`, but if you need to sum over a small number of values only (six months = up to six rows) you can apply a brute-force-approach:

```
AMT 
+
CASE WHEN LAG(DATE,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ATTRIBUTE ORDER BY DATE) >= ADD_MONTHS(DATE,-6) 
     THEN LAG(AMT,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ATTRIBUTE ORDER BY DATE)
     ELSE 0
END 
+
CASE WHEN LAG(DATE,2) OVER (PARTITION BY ATTRIBUTE ORDER BY DATE) >= ADD_MONTHS(DATE,-6) 
     THEN LAG(AMT,2)  OVER (PARTITION BY ATTRIBUTE ORDER BY DATE)
     ELSE 
END 
+
...
```

Looks ugly, but it's mostly cut&paste&modify and still a single step in Explain. Other possible solutions would be based on an additional EXPAND ON or time-series aggregation step.

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth for the response. I went for a different approach where I crossed joined with calendar tables to get one transaction per month (0 values for missing months) and then used PRECEDING ROW functions to calculate last 6 months cumulative sums. But thanks for your help as always!